# NPE when trying to Poll S3 using spring-integration-aws S3StreamingMessageSource

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-aws

I'm trying to poll an S3 object store using S3StreamMessageSource following the example here (under Streaming Inbound Channel Adapter): https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-aws/tree/v1.1.0.RELEASE

```
@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(value = "s3Channel", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "15000", maxMessagesPerPoll = "1"))
public MessageSource<InputStream> s3InboundStreamingMessageSource() {
    S3StreamingMessageSource messageSource = new S3StreamingMessageSource(s3RemoteFileTemplate());
    messageSource.setRemoteDirectory(s3Bucket+"/INBOX/");
    messageSource.setFilter(new S3SimplePatternFileListFilter("test*"));
    messageSource.setFilter(new S3PersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(new SimpleMetadataStore(), "s3Stream"));
    return messageSource;
}

@Bean
@org.springframework.integration.annotation.Transformer(inputChannel = "s3Channel", outputChannel = "nullChannel")
public Transformer transformer() {
    return new StreamTransformer();
}

@Bean
public S3RemoteFileTemplate s3RemoteFileTemplate() {
    return new S3RemoteFileTemplate(new S3SessionFactory(amazonS3));
}
```

but each time my app starts, a NPE is thrown:

```
2018-01-24 23:25:42.243 ERROR 29808 --- [ask-scheduler-1] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.lambda$run$0(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:396)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:53)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:51)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:373)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:93)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.integration.json.SimpleJsonSerializer.toElement(SimpleJsonSerializer.java:92)
    at org.springframework.integration.json.SimpleJsonSerializer.toJson(SimpleJsonSerializer.java:74)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.AbstractFileInfo.toJson(AbstractFileInfo.java:60)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.AbstractRemoteFileStreamingMessageSource.doReceive(AbstractRemoteFileStreamingMessageSource.java:164)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractMessageSource.receive(AbstractMessageSource.java:141)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.receiveMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:230)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:250)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.lambda$run$0(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:379)
    ... 13 more
```

when I step through where the exception is being thrown it's at the part of the code in **S3FileInfo.getPermissions**
and I see **UnsupportedOperationException "Use [AmazonS3.getObjectAcl()] to obtain permissions."**

What do I need to do to remedy this? I'm using Spring boot 1.5.9.RELEASE, spring-integration-aws 1.1.0.RELEASE, spring-integration-core 5.0.0.RELEASE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to use Spring Integration 5.0, you already have to switch to Spring Boot 2.0 and also Spring Integration AWS 2.0.

Or at least switch to the Spring Integration `5.0.1.BUIDL-SNAPSHOT`- the problem you mention has been fixed there recently: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/commit/34ffd9654d5ab4ada14fb3b34792d7019a1a34f4#diff-f473860eda832ea1371776cafd6809f9

Comment: Upgrading the Spring Integration Core jar to the recommended 5.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT fixed my NPE issue. Thanks Artem.

Comment: Good, we are going to release Spring Integration `5.0.1` the next Monday.